# Switch storybook background through global parameter

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have the following [globalTypes](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/toolbars-and-globals) to enable a toolbar in storybook that lets me select the theme:

```
export const globalTypes = {
  theme: {
    name: 'Theme',
    description: 'Global theme',
    defaultValue: MyTheme.Light,
    toolbar: {
      icon: 'mirror',
      items: [MyTheme.Light, MyTheme.Dark],
      showName: true,
      dynamicTitle: true,
    },
  },
};
```

This works fine and I can switch the theme through the toolbar:

[image: theme switcher]

Now I want to set the [background color of the story](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/backgrounds) (background-color of the body) according to the theme, but I cannot figure out how to do that for all stories globally.

I know how to configure different background colors, but I have no idea how to switch them based on the theme set in `context.globals`. How does this work?

Comment: Hi magnattic. Can you specify versions of your dependecies?

Comment: I am currently running storybook and it's  in version `6.5.10`, but could upgrade to latest if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [decorators](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators) to set global view and se

Like [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-dust-vv3w2n)

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./preview.css";

enum MyTheme {
  Light = "light",
  Dark = "dark",
  Tomato = "tomato"
}

export const globalTypes = {
  theme: {
    name: "Theme",
    description: "Global theme",
    defaultValue: MyTheme.Light,
    toolbar: {
      icon: "mirror",
      items: [
        {
          title: "light",
          value: MyTheme.Light
        },
        { title: "dark", value: MyTheme.Dark },
        { title: "tomato", value: MyTheme.Tomato }
      ],
      showName: true,
      dynamicTitle: true
    }
  }
};

const clearStyles = (element: HTMLElement) => {
  for (const className of Object.values(MyTheme)) {
    element.classList.remove(className);
  }
};

const applyStyle = (element: HTMLElement, className: string) => {
  element.classList.add(className);
};

const WithThemeProvider = (Story, context) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const body = window.document.body;
    clearStyles(body);
    applyStyle(body, context.globals.theme);
    return () => {
      clearStyles(body);
    };
  }, [context.globals.theme]);

  return <Story />;
};
export const decorators = [WithThemeProvider];
```

I know it might feel "dirty" to work directly with body. But it is suggested way for instance [addons decorator](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/create-an-addon/react/en/decorators/).

Comment: I am doing something similar right now, but this is not the same as switching the background color in storybook. The problem with this solution is that it only switches the content right around the component while background in storybook applies to the whole story.

Comment: To clarify, setting the background via [storybook backgrounds](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/backgrounds) actually changes the body color which looks a lot different than adding a surrounding div. That's what I would like to achieve. It's even possible with a URL parameter, but I can't figure out how to do this programmatically based on globals.

Comment: @magnattic Updated. In short just update body as html element.